# Examples where the product of reciprocal derivatives isn't one?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to understand why it isn't a good idea to treat derivatives like fractions. Could someone give me an example of a function $y$ such that $$\frac{dy}{dx} \cdot \frac{dx}{dy} \not = 1$$

This inspired my question, so I would appreciate it if someone could address it:

Conside a function
 $PV = kT$ for some constant $k$. Then $\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial V}\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial P}\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial T} = -1$ instead of $1$ as you would have expected if it's valid to treat derivatives "intuitively" as fractions.

Comment: For a silly example, any constant function doesn't work out well. A thing to take note of is that $dy/dx$ is a function of $x$ and so you should pay attention to where you are evaluating $dy/dx$ and $dx/dy$.

Comment: On the other hand, the equation is actually **true** as long as you assume $y=f(x)$ has a nice inverse function $x=f^{-1}(y)$. So this may not be the best way to illustrate why it isn't a good idea to treat derivatives like fractions.

Comment: What's the inverse of a constant function supposed to be? :)

Comment: Although formally you shouldn't treat derivatives as fractions, don't be afraid to use this interpretation as an intuitive technique when solving problems. If you treat it as a fraction you can usually solve many peculiar problems in calculus pretty quickly. Its just at the end you should justify the steps you make.

Comment: @S.Sheng That's what I've been doing so far, but I've come across a case in multivariable calculus where it hasn't worked. Consider the equation: $PV = kT$ for some constant $k$. Then $\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\frac{\partial T}{\partial P}\frac{\partial V}{\partial T} = -1$ instead of $1$ as you would have expected.

Comment: In general, derivatives with straight $d$'s work nicer with such cancellations than partial derivatives.

Comment: @theage Is there an "intuitive" reason why it doesn't work as well with partial derivatives?

Comment: Partial derivatives are PARTIAL derivatives.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, but it's still essentially the same concept of a small (infinitely small) amount of one variable being divided by a small amount of another.

Comment: chaosflaws:  Its easy enough to define the inverse of a constant function, but its only a relation, not a function  any more ...

Answer (score 8):

The "cancellation of fractions" is really a consequence of the inverse function theorem:

---

**Inverse Function Theorem**
*Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ be differentiable. Suppose that the Jacobian matrix of $f$, $Df(x)$ is invertible for some $x$. Then $f$ is locally invertible, and its inverse $f^{-1}$ satisfies*
$$D(f^{-1})(f(x))=Df(x)^{-1}$$

---

In the single-variable case, i.e. for $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable, then the Jacobian of $f$ is given by the $1\times 1$ matrix
$$Df(x)=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}\bigg|_x\end{bmatrix}$$
Remember that a linear map from $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is invertible if and only if it is non-zero. So the inverse function theorem takes the following form:

---

**Inverse Function Theorem (Single variable calc)**
*Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. Suppose that $\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}\big|_x\neq 0$ for some $x$. Then $f$ is locally invertible, and its inverse $f^{-1}$ satisfies*
$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\mathrm{d}f^{-1}}{\mathrm{d}x}\bigg|_{f(x)}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}\bigg|_x\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$

---

But the inverse of a $1\times 1$ matrix is just 
$$\begin{bmatrix}a\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{a}\end{bmatrix}$$
and so, letting $~y=f(x)$, 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y}\bigg|_{y}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\bigg|_x=1.~~\square$$

Comment: The Jacobian of $f$ in your statement of the IFT is non-square. What is the inverse of a non-square matrix?

Answer (score 2):

An intuitive way to see why
$$\frac{dx}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=1$$
would be if we treat the ratio as if it were *actually* a fraction. In particular, suppose that $x$ and $y$ are actually functions of some dummy variable - we could imagine, for instance, that they take on various values over time - but they happen to always satisfying some relation. Like, for instance, we could have $x$ be the volume of a balloon and $y$ be the pressure within. The two variables depend on time, but the quantity $\frac{dx}{dy}$ still makes sense - and can be interpreted equivalently either as the change in volume given a change in pressure OR literally as the ratio of those two derivatives where $dx$ is taken to be the derivative of $x$ with respect to the dummy variable time.

That this works is equivalent to the rule for composition of functions - that is the property that $(f\circ g)'(t)=f'(g(t))g'(t)$. In particular, suppose we had $x$ and $y$ related by $f$ so $x=f(y)$. Then, we take the derivative of both sides, where we write the derivative of $x$ as $dx$. Then we get:
$$dx = f'(y) dy$$
or, in other words, where $x$ and $y$ are functions of $t$
$$x'(t)=f'(y(t))y'(t)$$
by the rule for composition; note that we aren't differentiating with respect to any particular variable, and yet if we considered both $x$ and $y$ to be functions of their own, the values $dx$ and $dy$ are in fact well-defined, being simply the derivatives. So, we interpret the quantity 
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=f'(y)$$
to read that we literally want the ratio of those two derivatives - and the statement above: "$\frac{dx}{dy}$ is the derivative of the function relating $x$ to $y$" is a consequence of the product rule. Thus, we can legally cancel in the fractions, so long as neither derivative is $0$.

The same technique, unfortunately doesn't work for partial fractions, since if we tried to write out
$$x = f(y,z)$$
and differentiated to
$$dx = f_y(y,z)dy + f_z(y,z)dz$$
we would see that dividing by $dy$ or $dz$ would yield an expression dependent on either $\frac{dy}{dz}$ or $\frac{dz}{dy}$; the problem is that the above interpretation of derivatives only works well in a single variable, since it implicitly assumes that every variable is a function of a single dummy variable.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the OP's additional comments concerning partial derivatives, the multivariable chain rule exhibits quite clearly the absurdity of treating partial derivatives blindly as fractions.

Consider a composition of function
$$\mathbb{R}^2 \xrightarrow{f} \mathbb{R}^2 \xrightarrow{g} \mathbb{R}^2
$$
Inserting variables $(s,t)$ for the first $\mathbb{R}^2$, variables $(x,y)$ for the middle $\mathbb{R}^2$, and variables $(z,w)$ for the last $\mathbb{R}^2$, and writing coordinate functions for $f=(f_1,f_2)$ and for $g=(g_1,g_2)$, we can write this composition as
$$x = f_1(s,t), \quad y = f_2(s,t)
$$
$$z = g_1(x,y), \quad w = g_2(x,y)
$$
Assuming differentiability of the functions $f$ and $g$, the multivariable chain rule gives us a total of four equations expressing the partials of each of $z,w$ with respect to each of $s,t$. Here is just one of those four equations:
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial s} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial s}
$$
And now, if you are in a free-wheeling mood, cancel and add to get 
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial s} = 2 \frac{\partial z}{\partial s}
$$